# ios 7 TableViewController cells cannot be shown completely

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios7

I tried to update one of my IOS6 app to IOS7 using Xcode 5 GM which was just released couple of days ago.

One of the main problem I met is that some of the table views (UITableViewController) cannot be shown correctly anymore after being recompiled by IOS7 SDK:

Some of them cannot shown the last cells completely: You can see half of the last cell right there, but cannot scroll down to see full of it; some others cannot show the first cells completely: half of the cells was hide and you need to draw down the table view to see it.

BTW, those problematic tableViewControllers are all embedded in tab bar controllers.

Could anybody help me with this? Thanks.

### **UPDATE:**

I tried several ways, and here's my solution:

1. Delete the tab bar controllers, and add them back through editor->embed in->tab bar controller (I tried to drag out a tab bar controller from the object library directly, but that didn't fix the problem. Don't know why).
2. Re-link other view controllers to this new tab bar controller and run the app. Now, you probably see the first cell still cannot be show completely as I described before, but the last one can be shown correctly.
3. Go back to storyboard, select the tab bar controller and deselect "under top bars" in the attributes inspector. Run it again, everything works fine, at least for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a bug but rather a UI design as intended. As you can see the overlap of Tabbar still have some see through effect.

As I dont want to resize my table view to fit specific above the Tabbar.
Workaround with last cell bottom padding or add in extra last cell with same height as Tabbar?